# Reset AutoIncrement Column after deleting Datatable row c#

Tags: c#, webforms

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn STT = new DataColumn("STT");
STT.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
STT.AutoIncrement = true;
STT.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
STT.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dt .Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { STT....
```

Here is code

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
    if (int.Parse(dr["STT"].ToString()) == STTLine)
        dr.Delete();
}
```

Example 
Table 
STT| ...| ...|
 1 | 
 2 | 
 3 | 
 4 | 
when I delete 3th row, my STT column becomes 1 2 4. how do i reorder my datatable to 1 2 3 after deleting row. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand that you don't want to [`Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clear) data so `DataTable` does not support this functionality directly. However you can do this by dirty-solution as follow:

```
dt.Columns["STT"].ReadOnly = false;
int counter = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["STT"] = ++counter;
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
dt.Columns["STT"].ReadOnly = true;
```